# Is there a way to display a jinja variable name instead of it's value?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I'm writing a program in flask currently and I'm trying to see if I can display the name of a Jinja variable instead of the value it holds. For example:

```
{% set x = 0 %}
<button onclick="myFunction({{ x }})>
```

I'm trying to pass the variable into a javascript function but having the HTML show myFunction(x) instead of myFunction(0). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Seems like an x-y-probleme. Why do you want to display x?

Comment: @PatrickYoder sorry the question wasn't super clear, made some edits if those help.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Isn’t it the whole idea of variables that they contain values? The names of variables are irrelevant , they are just labels so you can use their values.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for(var key in objects) {
  var value = objects[key];
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please elaborate why this would be useful.